# How to split a string delimited by new lines in /bin/sh

Tags: unix, sh

I have a string like FIRSTNAME\nLASTNAME in a file. I want to put the first name and last name in their own variables. I have to use /bin/sh, not bash.

How can I easily do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use parameter expansion operators to strip everything following the `\n` as well as everything preceding it.

```
$ s="Stealth\nRabbi"
$ first=${s%\\n*}
$ last=${s#*\\n}
$ echo "$first"
Stealth
$ echo "$last"
Rabbi
```

Note that there are no literal newlines involved; you have two characters, `\` and `n`.